# Insert data in different sheets in Excel

Tags: python, excel

I would like to fill different data in different sheets in excel. So far i am writing everything in 1 sheet.

I want to have for each i in for loop a different sheet( sheet1,sheet2...)

```
for i in range(1,11):
    for k, v in drd_dictionary.items() :
        if str(i) + "_" in k :
            an.append(k)
            reqs.append(v)
    sheet_number=i
    write_to_excel(an,reqs,str(sheet_number))

def write_to_excel(an,req_text,sheet_number):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('path.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write_column('A1', an)
    worksheet.write_column('B1', req_text)

    workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're overwriting the workbook with each iteration.  Pass the workbook as a parameter to the function.  Initialize the workbook before the loop.

```
 def write_to_excel(workbook, an,req_text,sheet_number):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_number)
    worksheet.write_column('A1', an)
    worksheet.write_column('B1', req_text)
```

Here is the full working code:

```
import xlsxwriter

def write_to_excel(workbook, an,req_text,sheet_number):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(sheet_number)
    for i in range(len(an)):
        worksheet.write(0,i, an[i])
    for j in range(len(req_text)):
        worksheet.write(0,j, req_text[j])


drd_dictionary = {"1_": "a", "2_": "2"}
an,reqs = [],[]
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("data.xlsx")

for i in range(1,11):
    for k, v in drd_dictionary.items() :
        if str(i) + "_" in k :
            an.append(k)
            reqs.append(v)
    sheet_number=i
    write_to_excel(workbook, an,reqs,str(sheet_number))

workbook.close()
```

Comment: I tried it and it creates only the first sheet(number 1). I don't know if i am doing something wrong

Comment: Thank you. What i did wrong was that i forgot the workbook.close() inside my function.Thanks!